# "Not enough space for thread data R6016" Python multiprocessing error showing not enough thread space

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, similarity, hierarchical-clustering, thread-exceptions

I am currently trying to create Hierarchical Clustering using Similarity Matrix on a dataset of 35K images. I am trying to build the similarity matrix by concatenating Gabor filters, zernike moments and HOG of the images. AS the process was slow, I tried using multiprocessing and assign multiple threads. i split it into 4 threads and concatenated the result received at the end of each thread. But there is an error stating "not enough space for thread data R6016 " The program continues after I press ok button. But the task is being interrupted frequently and I need to press the ok button. Can anyone tell me how to get around it?

The code is:

```
from hog_feature import HOGFeature
from gabor_feature3 import GaborFeatures
from zernike_moments import ZernikeMoments
import csv
import pyexcel as pe
import time
import cv2
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist


class HierarchicalCluster:
    def __init__(self):
        self.similarity_matrix = []
        self.location = []
        self.gabor = GaborFeatures()
        self.zernike = ZernikeMoments()
        self.hog = HOGFeature()
        self.filters = self.gabor.build_filters()
        self.w_g = 0.33
        self.w_z = 0.33
        self.w_h = 0.33

    # extracting info from csv file
    def extract_location(self):
        with open('OSU_gps_GrahamCreek.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for row in reader:
                self.location.append(row[3])
        return self.location

    def tailend_extract(self, image1, image2):
        feature_g = Queue()
        feature_z = Queue()
        feature_h = Queue()
        feature_extract = []
        # gabor process
        g1 = Process(target=self.gabor.feature_extract_image1, args=(image1, feature_g, self.filters))
        g2 = Process(target=self.gabor.feature_extract_image1, args=(image2, feature_g, self.filters))
        # zernike process
        z1 = Process(target=self.zernike.zernike_dist, args=(image1, image2, feature_z))
        # hog feature
        h1 = Process(target=self.hog.feature_extract, args=(image1, image2, feature_h))
        # start processes
        g1.start()
        g2.start()
        z1.start()
        h1.start()
        image1_gf = feature_g.get()

        image2_gf = feature_g.get()

        dist_z = feature_z.get()

        dist_h = feature_h.get()
        if dist_h < 0:
            dist_h = 0.0
        g1.join()
        g2.join()
        z1.join()
        h1.join()
        feature_h.close()
        feature_z.close()
        feature_g.close()
        # calculate gabor distance
        dist_g = (dist.euclidean(image1_gf,image2_gf))*(10**(-13))
        pairwise_feature = (self.w_g * dist_g) + (self.w_z * dist_z) + (self.w_h * dist_h)
        #print pairwise_feature
        return pairwise_feature



    def pairwise_similarity(self, location):

        for i in range(len(location)):
            s = time.time()
            pairwise_similarity_matrix = []
            image_p = cv2.imread(location[i], flags=cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            if i >= 1:
                for j in range(0,i):
                    pairwise_similarity_matrix.append(self.similarity_matrix[j][i])
            for j in range(i, len(location)):
                if i==j:
                    pairwise_similarity_matrix.append(0.0)
                else:
                    image_q = cv2.imread(location[j], flags=cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                    distance = self.tailend_extract(image_p,image_q)
                    pairwise_similarity_matrix.append(distance)
                print (str(i) + ":" + str(j))
            self.similarity_matrix.append(pairwise_similarity_matrix)
            #print (time.time() - s)
        return self.similarity_matrix

    def pairwise_similarity_test(self, image1, image2):
        gabor_feature = self.gabor.get_distance(img1=image1, img2=image2)
        zernike_feature = self.zernike.get_distance(img1=image1, img2=image2)
        hog_feature = self.hog.get_distance(img1=image1, img2=image2)
        pairwise_feature = self.w_g*gabor_feature + self.w_z*zernike_feature + self.w_h*hog_feature
        print pairwise_feature

    def create_csv(self, similarity_matrix):

        sheet = pe.Sheet(similarity_matrix)
        sheet.save_as("similarity_matrix_GC.csv")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    cluster = HierarchicalCluster()
    locations = cluster.extract_location()
    similarity = cluster.pairwise_similarity(locations)
    print similarity
    cluster.create_csv(similarity)
```

In here the zernike, gabor and HOG are just different classes that I am using to extract vectors.

The error shows as:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjpZd.png)

Thank you in advance for the help